# How to stop string from replacing previous elements?

Tags: c, string, strtok

I'm trying to run this program that reads an input of type `str:int:int:int` and then splits the values into their respective arrays. The problem is the string part keeps getting replaced everytime the function runs. This is my code:

```
 int main(){
        char *str[100];
        int stock[100][3],idp=0;

        while(idp<100){
          fgets(data,80,stdin);
          str[idp]=strtok(data,":");
          stock[idp][0]=atoi(strtok(NULL,":"));
          stock[idp][1]=atoi(strtok(NULL,":"));
          stock[idp][2]=atoi(strtok(NULL,":"));
          idp++;
        }
    return 0;
    }
```

After running the `while()` cycle 3 times with the inputs `abc:3:4:5` `abcde:1:5:6` `def:5:6:7` i get the following values:

```
str[0]=def stock[0][0]=3 stock[0][1]=4 stock[0][2]=5
str[1]=def stock[1][0]=1 stock[1][1]=5 stock[1][2]=6
str[2]=def stock[2][0]=5 stock[2][1]=6 stock[2][2]=7
```

As you can see, while the values of the `stock[][]` array are getting stored correctly,all of the previous strings on the `str[]` array are getting replaced. I'd like to know how to stop this from happening. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't really copy the result just setting your pointers to the same address.

Comment: And how do i set a different address? I want all the strings in the same array for that matter.

Comment: `str[idp]=strdup(strtok(data,":"));`

Comment: Please note that `strdup` is not part of the official C standard, so it may not work on all compilers. The function [strcpy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) works on all compilers though, but it requires you to first allocate sufficient memory to store the copy of the string.

Comment: @Eraklon Ah so that's the problem. Thanks. I have another small issue though: When `str[i]` is less than 4 characters long, one random digit is added to `stock[i][2]` for each character missing. How do I fix that?

Comment: @FranciscoCunha Thats strange. Will check it out.

Comment: @Eraklon When I applied your answer, it stopped happening. But still really strange .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You making shallow copies. You need real copies. One way is to make `str` a 2D array like `char str[100][80]`. Then instead of this

```
str[idp]=strtok(data,":");
```

do this

```
strcpy(str[idp], strtok(data,":"));
```

Also if your input is strictly that format you could use `sscanf` instead of `atoi`s and `strcpy`. Like this

```
sscanf(data, "%[^:]:%d:%d:%d", str[idp], &stock[idp][0], &stock[idp][1], &stock[idp][2]);
```

`%[^:]` will read in characters which not `:`.

Answer (score 1):

In these statements

```
      fgets(data,80,stdin);
      str[idp]=strtok(data,":");
```

pointers `str[idp]` are always set to the address inside the same variable data. So what the variable stores in the current moment is what the pointers point to.

You have to make copies of the pointed strings.

That is you need to declare a two dimensional arrau of characters liek for example

```
char str[100][10];
```

and then write for example

```
strcpy( str[idp], strtok(data,":") );
```